# Why returning double from float returning method does not cause any error/warning in c++

Tags: java, c++, g++, javac

Well I was trying to compile following code (just a snippet) in `Java`:

```
class MyClass{
        public float get100(){
        return 100.05;  // returning 100.05f should work
    }
}
```

But as you can see `100.5` being a `double` in nature but `get100()` is returning `float` by its declaration, `javac` gives error as: `can't convert double to float`.

Which is totally understandable. But Here is what i noticed about `c++`

I tried following code (Almost similar to the one mentioned above):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class MyClass{
        public:
               float get100(){
                    return 100.05;
               }
};

int main(){
MyClass m;
cout<<m.get100()<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

and this code is running fine in `c++`..

Can anyone tell me why is it so? or does it mean `c++` compiler is smart enough that it can auto convert `double` to `float`?

But as `double` is of higher range than `float`, how is that working in `c++`?

Any help/Suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Java and C++ are different languages. 2) Compilers don't randomly make up behaviours. They follow rules.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the C++ compiler is smart enough that it can auto convert double to float. The Java compiler *could* do the same thing, but the designers of Java decided that it's better to not allow it, in case it is a mistake by the programmer.

Answer (score 2):

[cppreference.com on implicit conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast):

> Floating point conversions
>
> A prvalue of an floating-point type can be converted to prvalue of any other floating-point type. If the conversion is listed under floating-point promotions, it is a promotion and not a conversion.
>
> - If the source value can be represented exactly in the destination type, it does not change.
> - If the source value is between two representable values of the destination type, the result is one of those two values (it is implementation-defined which one)
> - Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Here, the case is the second rule. `100.05` is not exactly representable as a `float` *or* a `double`. For values such as `0.375` or `34`, the first rule would be applied, as the source value can be represented exactly.

As for Java, a `return` is an assignment context. [JLS§5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) states:

> Assignment contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>   * an identity conversion (§5.1.1)
>   * a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2)
>   * a widening reference conversion (§5.1.5)
>   * a boxing conversion (§5.1.7) optionally followed by a widening reference conversion
>   * an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) optionally followed by a widening primitive conversion.

Note that an implicit narrowing conversion is *not* permitted here, unless the value being returned is a constant value (i.e. a final field, or literal expression the compiler can evalulate).